# Matplotlib does not assign color to bar with height 0

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

I want to change the colors of the bars in my plot to be:

- 1990 - 1999: red
- 2000 - 2009: blue
- 2010 - 2022: green

But Matplotlib doesn't assign color to bars with height 0.

Then I created a list with this colors:

`colors = ['red' if 1990 <= year <= 1999 else 'blue' if 2000 <= year <= 2009 else 'green' for year in range(1999, 2023)]`

Then i set `plt.bar` parameter:

`plt.bar(table['Year'], table['Occurrences'], color = colors)`

But when the value of some bar is 0, the colors is not assigned:

Example with all heights positive:

[image]

Example with height 0:

[image]

You can see that the code works when the bars have height, but in the second plot, the bars with 0 are not assigned colors, so it respective colors are assigned to the next bar with positive height. How to make Matplotlib to respect the position of the colors?

Answer (score 0):

**Example code**

we need minimal and reproducible example for solving problem

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'year':[1990, 1999, 2002, 2021], 'value':[30, 0, 15, 20]})
```

df:

```
    year    value
0   1990    30
1   1999    0
2   2002    15
3   2021    20
```

**Code**

make colormap by using year column

```
import numpy as np
cond1 = df['year'].between(1990, 1999)
cond2 = df['year'].between(2000, 2009)
colormap = np.select([cond1, cond2], ['red', 'blue'], 'green')
```

colormap:

```
array(['red', 'red', 'blue', 'green'], dtype='<U5')
```

make plot using `colormap`

```
df.plot(kind='bar', x='year', y='value', color=colormap, legend=False)
```

[image]

1990 - 1999: red, 2000 - 2009: blue, 2010 - 2022 : green

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is not reproducible neither with `matplotlib` nor with `pandas`

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

np.random.seed(2023)
table = pd.DataFrame({'Year': np.arange(1990, 2023),
                      'Occurrences': np.random.choice([10, 20, 30, 0], 33)})
colors = ['red' if 1990 <= year <= 1999
          else 'blue' if 2000 <= year <= 2009
          else 'green' for year in range(1990, 2023)]
```

Output with `pandas`:

```
>>> table.plot.bar(x='Year', y='Occurrences', color=colors, legend=False)
```

[image]

Output with `matplotlib`:

```
>>> plt.bar(table['Year'], table['Occurrences'], color=colors)
```

[image]

However if there is a missing year in your `table`, colors seem to be "shifted":

```
# remove 1993, 2000 is now red (and not blue), 2010 is now blue (and not green)
>>> plt.bar(table['Year'].drop(3), table['Occurrences'].drop(3), color=colors)
```

[image]

I think there is a missing year in your table. Try:

```
>>> set(np.arange(1990, 2023)).difference(table['Year'])  # I removed 1993 here
{1993}  # <- missing year(s)
```

To get a full table with all years, do:

```
table = table.set_index('Year').reindex(np.arange(1990, 2023), fill_value=0).reset_index()
```

Now you can plot your chart.